# Test kafka behaviour when disconnecting one broker (spring-kafka)

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-partition

I'm starting in Kafka.

I have one cluster with 2 broker (ids #2 and #3), and a replication factor of 2.
I want to test the bahaviour of Kafka if I disconnect one broker (id #3).

After the shutdown of the #3, my topic informations:

```
Topic: CUSTOMER PartitionCount: 5       ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs:
        Topic: CUSTOMER Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2
        Topic: CUSTOMER Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2
        Topic: CUSTOMER Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2
        Topic: CUSTOMER Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2
        Topic: CUSTOMER Partition: 4    Leader: 2       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2
```

Each partition is replicated on every brokers and now the #2 broker is the leader, that's OK.

The publishing of the message is OK, but it's not consumed by my consumer service (I'm using Spring-kafka).

At the disconnection moment, the consumer logs are:

```
2020-04-01 14:51:42.736  INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator:677        [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=NOTIF] Discovered group coordinator 10.0.0.0:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-04-01 14:51:42.737  INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator:729        [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=NOTIF] Group coordinator 10.0.0.0:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-04-01 14:51:42.840  INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator:677        [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=NOTIF] Discovered group coordinator 10.0.0.0:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2020-04-01 14:51:42.841  WARN [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:671         [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=NOTIF] Connection to node 2147483644 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-04-01 14:51:42.841  INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator:729        [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=NOTIF] Group coordinator 10.0.0.0:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-04-01 14:51:42.842  WARN [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:671         [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=NOTIF] Connection to node 3 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-04-01 14:51:43.136  WARN [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:671         [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=NOTIF] Connection to node 3 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-04-01 14:51:43.184  WARN [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:671         [][][] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=NOTIF] Connection to node 3 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Then nothing.
And nothing in the zookeeper logs.

When I start my broker, all the messages are now consumed.

Can you tell me if I'm wrong?
With my topic configuration, I assume that the disconnection of one broker should be possible with no impact.

My kafka configuration:

```
broker.id=2 (not the same value on the other broker)
delete.topic.enable=true
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/usr/share/kafka/logs
num.partitions=2
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=48
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=serv2:2181,serv3:2181,serv5:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
default.replication.factor=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
```

And my zookeeper configuration :

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/usr/share/zookeeper/data
server.2=serv2:2888:3888;2181
server.3=serv3:2888:3888;2181
server.5=serv5:2888:3888;2181
```

I create the topic with Spring Kafka:

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }
    @Bean
    public NewTopic notifTopic() {
        return new NewTopic(notifTopic, partitions, (short) bootstrapAddress.split(",").length);
    }
```

And for the consumer:
Config :

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@Profile({ "!mockKafka & !test" })
public class KafkaConfiguration implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.groups.notif.name}")
    private String notifGroup;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> containerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Object>(getConsumerFactoryProperties()));
        factory.setConcurrency(5);
        return factory;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getConsumerFactoryProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, notifGroup);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return props;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setValidator(validator);
    }

}
```

Listener:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Profile({"!mockKafka & !test"})
@Transactional
@KafkaListener(containerFactory = "containerFactory", topics = { "${kafka.topics.notif.name}" })
public class NotificationListener { 

    @KafkaHandler
    public void email(@Payload @Valid EmailNotification record, @Header(ContextUtils.HEADER_ACCOUNT) String account,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) long partition) {
        log.info("Consuming message [EMAIL] from topic [{}], partition [{}], offset [{}]", topic, partition, offset);
        ...
    }
```

and my global configurations:

```
kafka:
    servers: serv2:9092,serv3:9092
    publish.timeout: 3000
    partitions: 5
    topics:
        customer:
            name: CUSTOMER
        notif:
            name: NOTIF
        health:
            name: HEALTH
    groups:
        customer:
            name: CUSTOMER
        notif:
            name: NOTIF
```

Versions used:
Kafka : 2.4.0
Zookeeper: 3.5.6
Spring-kafka : 2.2.12

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show your configuration properties.

Comment: Please edit the question instead - it's too hard to read in a comment. Also show your Spring Boot configuration. Also provide version information.

Comment: I need to see the properties too, e.g. `kafka.servers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
```

Since the offsets are not replicated the consumer can't find its position.

According to the docs, the default is 3 (if omitted); but it comes with it overridden to 1 (at least in my homebrew dist).

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try with this configuration.
I assume I should remove my existing topics?

Comment: I am not sure; I would expect kafka to replicate the offsets topics (offsets are kept in a different topic). You can check the replication factor of those topics the same way that you have with your CUSTOMER topic after you reconfigure the brokers. The topic is called `__consumer_offsets`. `$ kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets`.